# My Magento wishlist doesn’t work

Tags: magento

I am running the `Magento` version `1.5.0.1` and I have a problem with the wishlist.

If the visitor clicks `Add to wishlist` without being logged in, the website redirects them to the `login` or `register` page, that's OK. The problem is that once the user create the account or log in, the wishlist is empty or that product never where added to the wishlist.

If the user is logged in and clicks "Add to wishlist" it works perfectly. 
I appreciate any comment.

Comment: I have reviewed it again and the Wishlist module isn’t enable, the reason is that they use Webtex Gift Registry Extension as wishlist. this a website I just have to put some work for maintenance so I didn’t build it and not a clue where do I need to start.

Any suggestions?

Thanks again.